# Remove duplicates of array from another array, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, duplicates

How can i remove duplicated arrays in this data structure?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I got this:

```
    ["5", "26", 300],
    ["7", "10", 20],
    ["3", "4", 30],
    ["5", "2", 52],
    ["9", "5", 300],
    ["3", "4", 30],
    ["5", "2", 52],
    ["5", "26", 300],
    ["1", "27", 250]
```

with:

```
var all = [].concat(jsonData['l'],jsonData['c'], jsonData['r']);                                    
for (e in all){
    console.log([all[e].source, all[e].target, Number(all[e].link)]);
}
```

I need to reduce data, remove duplicated arrays and provide result to sankey graf. jsonData elements contain much more data and structure of each left, center and right side is a little bit diffrent.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MvXz.png

Comment: please add the array as text and add you code

Comment: What specifically are you having problems with? The general approach is pretty simple: iterate over the array and only add the values to the output array which you haven't seen yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `filter` them:

```js
var a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], ['foo']];
var tmp = [];

var b = a.filter(function (v) {
    if (tmp.indexOf(v.toString()) < 0) {
        tmp.push(v.toString());
        return v;
    }
});

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

In [this other reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44014849/5710581) it was resolved stringifying the arrays, and removing duplicates with a Set. It should be much simpler

```
Array.from(new Set(jsonData.map(JSON.stringify)), JSON.parse)
```