# javascript: how to remove duplicate arrays inside array of arrays

Tags: javascript

Input:

```
[[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]]
```

The output I want:

```
[[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]
```

Any other ideas except [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014530/remove-duplicates-of-array-from-another-array-javascript)?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why we shouldn't close this as a duplicate of the question you yourself linked to? Did the solution in that question not work for you?

Comment: Agreed. That looks like a pretty good solution.

Comment: @nnnnnn Because that's a horrible and slow approach?

Comment: Its the semantics that are worrisome. Is identity really definable by `toString` for all values?

Comment: @Bergi - But it's still the same requirement, right?

Comment: If you're data is actually more complicated than just integers, you could use this method for comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: @nnnnnn Maybe, the other question isn't as succinct - and it's not tagged [es6] either :-)

Comment: `[[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]].filter((a, i) => x.findIndex(b => a[0]===b[0] && a[1]===b[1] && a[2]===b[2]) === i)` will work. Not sure about speed though. O(n^2) most likely.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with es2015 so I removed the tag :p

Comment: @BAE don't forget to accept best answer (by clicking on gray "check" button on its left side)

Answer (score 35):

You won't really get around stringifying the arrays, as that's the simplest (and reasonably fast) way to compare them by value. So I'd go for

```
Array.from(new Set(input.map(JSON.stringify)), JSON.parse)
```

See also [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9229645/1048572) for other approaches, though most of them will require two values to be comparable by `===`.

Comment: While I agree that this works, I'd be concerned about the 2nd and 3rd arguments that `JSON.stringify()` will receive from `.map()` interfering with it in some implementation, since the 2nd argument is supposed to be either `null` or a function, and the 3rd argument is supposed to be a number or a string.

Answer (score 20):

## Magic

```
d.filter(( t={}, a=> !(t[a]=a in t) ));
```

I assume your input data are in array `d`. Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53453045/860099).

```js
let d = [[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]];

var r = d.filter((t={},a=>!(t[a]=a in t)));

console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
```

Comment: Sometimes I have to declare t first, sometimes I don't, so weird.

Comment: looks like its strict mode when it yells about a referenceerror for t

Comment: This relies on string coercion of arrays, which fails for cases like `[ [ "a", "b" ], [ "a,b" ] ]`.

Answer (score 6):

There's already a good utility for that, try [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqWith), one of the function of it is _.uniqWith, with that function you can do the following.

```
<script src="/path/to/lodash.js"></script>
<script>
    var aa = [[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]];
    console.log(aa);
    console.log(_.uniqWith(aa,_.isEqual));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a hashMap and save values in it. This will always hold last value.

```js
var data = [[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]]

var hashMap = {}

data.forEach(function(arr){
  // If your subArrays can be in any order, you can use .sort to have consistant order
  hashMap[arr.join("|")] = arr;
});

var result = Object.keys(hashMap).map(function(k){
  return hashMap[k]
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This fails for `[ [ "a", "b" ], [ "a|b" ] ]`.

Comment: If you change input structure, any algorithm will fail.

Comment: The input structure is the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
const removeDuplicates = (arr = []) => {
    const map = new Map();
    arr.forEach((x) => map.set(JSON.stringify(x), x));
    arr = [...map.values()];
    return arr;
};

console.log(
    removeDuplicates([
        [1, 1, 6],
        [1, 2, 5],
        [1, 7],
        [1, 2, 5],
        [1, 7],
        [2, 6],
    ])
);
// we can use simple JS object also to store unique elements  like { "[1, 1, 6]" : [1, 1, 6]  }
//resource - https://hackinbits.com/articles/how-to-iterate-a-map-in-javascript---map-part-2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1275o6g/7/)

Borrowing the array comparison code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

```
// Warn if overriding existing method
if(Array.prototype.equals)
    console.warn("Overriding existing Array.prototype.equals. Possible causes: New API defines the method, there's a framework conflict or you've got double inclusions in your code.");
// attach the .equals method to Array's prototype to call it on any array
Array.prototype.equals = function (array) {
    // if the other array is a falsy value, return
    if (!array)
        return false;

    // compare lengths - can save a lot of time 
    if (this.length != array.length)
        return false;

    for (var i = 0, l=this.length; i < l; i++) {
        // Check if we have nested arrays
        if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) {
            // recurse into the nested arrays
            if (!this[i].equals(array[i]))
                return false;       
        }           
        else if (this[i] != array[i]) { 
            // Warning - two different object instances will never be equal: {x:20} != {x:20}
            return false;   
        }           
    }       
    return true;
}

var old = [[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]], n = [];

while(old.length) {
    var arr = old.shift(), matched = false;

  for(var i = 0, len = n.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (arr.equals(n[i])) {
        matched = true;
        break;
    }
  }
  if (!matched) {
    n.push(arr);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would one use `instanceof` over `Array.isArray`? I am just curious.

Comment: There's not really any difference. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289727/difference-between-using-array-isarray-and-instanceof-array

Answer (score -1):

If you want to prevent duplicates in array during construction:

```
if (!arr.includes(subArray)) {
  arr.push(subArray)
}
```