# What's the most elegant way in ES6 to filter out duplicates in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I've seen alot of answers to this topic but I'm not completely satisfied. The snippet I liked the most was this one:

```
[ ["1", "2"], ["1", "2", "3"], ["1", "2"] ]
  .filter(
    (path: string[], i: number, array: string[][]) => _.findIndex(array, x => _.isEqual(x, path)) === i
  )
```

This works but I find it waaaayy too verbose for my liking. Isn't there a more compact way to achieve this? Even if it means using lodash or something. I feel I'm missing something really obvious in the year 2019 (nearly 2020).

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014799/javascript-how-to-remove-duplicate-arrays-inside-array-of-arrays

Comment: Based on the accepted answer looks like it is a not-RTFM problem.

Comment: I (like many others) looked into lodash documentation but somehow we couldn't find .uniqWith(). Sorry we are not as perfect as you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With lodash you can use [`_.uniqWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqWith) to deduplicate the array, and use `_.isEqual()` as the comparator:

```js
const array = [["1", "2"], ["1", "2", "3"], ["1", "2"]]

const result = _.uniqWith(array, _.isEqual)

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a bunch of closures and check with a `Set` and a stringified value.

```js
var array = [["1", "2"], ["1", "2", "3"], ["1", "2"]],
    unique = array.filter(
        (s => a => 
            (j => !s.has(j) && s.add(j))
            (JSON.stringify(a))
        )
        (new Set)    
    );

console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score -1):

Many ways actually, try to play in browser console. I usually using most straightforward with primitives:

```
const uniques = [...new Set(originalArray)]
```

For objects harder:

```
const uniques = original.reduce((result, object) => {
  if (!result.find((o) => i._id === object._id)) {
    result.push(object);
  }
  return result;
}, [])
```